# Signed measures: Why is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\geqslant n}\varphi(A_k)=0$?

Tags: measure-theory

> > **Definition** (*signed measure*). Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A})$ be a measurable space. A function $\varphi\colon\mathfrak{A}\to\mathbb{R}$ is called *signed measure* if (1) $\varphi(\emptyset)=0$ and (2) $\varphi(\biguplus_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\varphi(A_n)$ for pairwise disjoint $A_n\in\mathfrak{A}$.

Now there is a statement in my script that I do not understand, namely:

> > Because for all $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ it is $\varphi(A)\in\mathbb{R}$ and therefore $\lvert\varphi(A)\rvert<\infty$ it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\geqslant n}\varphi(A_k)=0$ for pairwise disjoint $A_n$.

Could you please explain that to me? Why does from $\varphi(A)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lvert\varphi(A)\rvert<\infty$ for all $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ follow that
$$
\lim_n\sum_{k\geqslant n}\varphi(A_k)=0?
$$

I thought about that but could not find how to show this. Maybe it's not that difficult but I seem to be blind.

Greetings

Miro

Comment: Why do you write unions as $\biguplus$?

Comment: In our lecture $\biguplus$ always was for union of pairwise disjoint sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\cup_k A_k$. Then we have $\sum_k \varphi(A_k)=\varphi (A) \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\sum_k \varphi(A_k)$ is a converging series of real numbers. By definition, this means that its partial sums converge and thus, the remainder $\sum_{k \geq n} \varphi(A_k)$ converge to zero for $n \rightarrow \infty$.